# Did webassembly support openmp?

Tags: openmp, webassembly, asm.js

As title , anyone know webassembly support openmp or not?
If support, how to use it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, WebAssembly does not support OpenMP - WebAssembly is an assembly language for the web. If you have the sourcecode for OpenMP, and it is in C or C++, you might be able to compile it to WebAssembly using Emscripten.